# C# Cell merge in devexpress gridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the event cell merge doing some actions
but the problem is everytime i scroll the grid its always triggering that event

what i want to know is if there is a way to do what i do in the cellmerge event but only once and not everytime i do something in the grid
the way to go i think would be creating a function and i only call it once instead of using a grid event  but i dont know how to do that and i dont even know if its possible to do

this what i do in the cellmerge event:

```
 private void gridViewCompras_CellMerge(object sender, CellMergeEventArgs e)
        {
                if (e.Column.FieldName == ColNecessidades1)
                {
                    GridView view = sender as GridView;


                    string ref1 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle1, ColReferencia);
                    string ref2 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle2, ColReferencia);
                    string esp1 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle1, ColEspessura);
                    string esp2 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle2, ColEspessura);
                    string acab1 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle1, ColAcabamento);
                    string acab2 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle2, ColAcabamento);
                    double value1 = Convert.ToDouble(view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle1, ColNecessidades1));
                    double value2 = Convert.ToDouble(view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle2, ColNecessidades1));


                    if (ref1 == ref2 && esp1 == esp2 && acab1 == acab2)
                    {
                        double resultsoma = (value1) + (value2);
                        gridViewCompras.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle1, ColNecessidades1, Convert.ToString(resultsoma));
                        e.Merge = true;
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                }

                if (e.Column.FieldName == ColNecessidades2)
                {
                    GridView view = sender as GridView;

                    string ref1 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle1, ColReferencia);
                    string ref2 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle2, ColReferencia);
                    string esp1 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle1, ColEspessura);
                    string esp2 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle2, ColEspessura);
                    string acab1 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle1, ColAcabamento);
                    string acab2 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle2, ColAcabamento);
                    double value1 = Convert.ToDouble(view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle1, ColNecessidades2));
                    double value2 = Convert.ToDouble(view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle2, ColNecessidades2));


                    if (ref1 == ref2 && esp1 == esp2 && acab1 == acab2)
                    {
                        double resultsoma = (value1) + (value2);
                        gridViewCompras.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle1, ColNecessidades2, Convert.ToString(resultsoma));
                        e.Merge = true;
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                }

                if (e.Column.FieldName == ColNecessidades6)
                {
                    GridView view = sender as GridView;

                    string ref1 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle1, ColReferencia);
                    string ref2 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle2, ColReferencia);
                    string esp1 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle1, ColEspessura);
                    string esp2 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle2, ColEspessura);
                    string acab1 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle1, ColAcabamento);
                    string acab2 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle2, ColAcabamento);
                    double value1 = Convert.ToDouble(view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle1, ColNecessidades6));
                    double value2 = Convert.ToDouble(view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle2, ColNecessidades6));


                    if (ref1 == ref2 && esp1 == esp2 && acab1 == acab2)
                    {
                        double resultsoma = (value1) + (value2);
                        gridViewCompras.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle1, ColNecessidades6, Convert.ToString(resultsoma));
                        e.Merge = true;
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event being called repeatedly when scrolling is totally expected behavior and to my knowledge there is no way around it.

To prevent unecessary memory usage, DevExpress' GridControl uses virtualization to create/reuse visuals. This means that upon scrolling, the visuals for formerly non-visible rows are created/reused and -necessarily- the CellMerge-event is triggered repeatedly to evaluate mergeability of new- or reused cells.

Note that several other operations on the GridView (sorting, filtering etc.) require reevaluation of cell-merge as well. However, the GridControl internally 'knows' quite well when the reevaluation is actually needed and does not trigger the merge event without good reason.

tldr: no need to worry - you did everything the way DevExpress [intended it to be done](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114730/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/getting-started/walkthroughs/grid-view-columns-rows-and-cells/tutorial-cell-merging)

**Edit** regarding your comment and the issue of summarizing cell-values within the CellMerge-event: thats not a good idea as you can tell from the results you described. The following might be worth a try:

1. create a summary-field on your ItemsSource/list elements
2. before assigning the elements as ItemsSource, apply your summary logic
3. during the CellMerge-event just check if the summaries are equal and merge cells accordingly

...and right away -as proposed in your question- the summary logic only needs to be applied a single time.

Comment: the thing is i have a sum there everytime you scroll it keeps adding up (lets say the total is 10k for example if i scroll again it goes to 20k scroll again 30k )when the actual sum value is 10k 
thats why i asked if there is  another way to do this.

what im realising is what i want to do cant be done